# NA as input in aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to execute the aes_string function also when not providing all variables that are supposed to be defined in aes_string according to my code. The code:

```
test <- function(data, x, y, c){
    ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes_string(x = x, y = y, colour = c))
}
```

I would like to be able to execute it also when I do not have any colour variable as input to it, e.g.:

```
test(data, 'x', 'y', NA)
```

or

```
test(data, 'x', 'y', '')
```

or similar, but I do not know which value I can enter as c for ggplot to not take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
test(data, 'x', 'y', FALSE)
```

made the job.

Comment: This usually adds a colour scale "FALSE" to the graph which is undesirable (see `test(iris, 'Petal.Width', 'Petal.Length', FALSE) + geom_point()`). Try `NULL`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee : If I try NULL it also throws me an error.

Comment: In this case you must provide a reproducible example as well as the precise error message you are getting - the code I asked you to try with `iris` certainly works, so there must be something else causing your error.